# Valor Undefined en mi función

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

estoy estudiando Javascript y en una de las tareas tengo que recibir datos de un estudiante y decirle si aprobó, debe rendir examen o si reprobó. Las primeras líneas iba todo bien hasta el momento que tuve que unir todo lo anterior en una función (final) para que lo evalúe y devuelva un mensaje si el alumno aprobó y las notas. Cuestión **al probar la función final para ver si iba bien en consola me devuelve el mensaje Undefined en las partes que debería leer la variable**, podrían darme una mano y explicarme qué está mal? Muchas gracias, saludos!

```js
var datos = [];

function agregarEstudiante(nombre, pef, pei, peo, ef, ei, eo, ppi, ct) {
    datos.push({
        nombre: nombre,
        pef: pef, // Puntaje eval. Fundamentos
        pei: pei, // Puntaje eval. prog. Imperativa
        peo: peo, // Puntaje eval. POO
        ef: ef, // Evidencia Fundamentos
        ei: ei, // Evidencia Imperativa
        eo: eo, // Evidencia POO
        ppi: ppi, // Promedio Ingles
        ct: ct, // Lecciones CT
    });
}
agregarEstudiante("Juan", 100, 100 , 100, true, true, true, 80, 10);
agregarEstudiante("Pedro", 90, 60 , 50, true, false, true, 90, 9);

var apruebaInglesCT = []
var pierdeFase1 = []
function fase1(datos){
        if(datos.ppi >= 50 && datos.ct === 10){
            apruebaInglesCT.push(datos.nombre);
        } else{
            pierdeFase1.push(datos.nombre);
        }
}
datos.forEach(fase1);

var apruebaTecnico = []
var rindeExamen = []
var pierdeTecnico = [];
function tecnica(datos){
    var prom = ((datos.pef * 0.3) + (datos.pei * 0.5) + (datos.peo * 0.2) );
    if ((prom >= 60) && (datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)){
        apruebaTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
    }
    else if ((prom >= 60) && !(datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)){
        rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre + prom);

    }
    else if ((prom >= 50 && prom < 60) && (datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)){
        rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre + prom);
    }
    else {
        pierdeTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
    }
}
datos.forEach(tecnica);

function final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico){
    var msj = [];
    if (apruebaInglesCT && apruebaTecnico){
        msj = console.log("Hola " + datos.nombre + "!!, el detalle de tu status final es: \n En Inglés - " + datos.ppi + " puntos- ok");
        //console.log(msj);
    } else {
        console.log("nada");
    }
}
final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico);
```

Comment: que es exactamente lo que debes imprimir? las personas dentro de 'datos' y si aprobaron ingles y tecnico?

Comment: Hola infinit, tengo que en base a las variables ** apruebaInglesCT, pierdeFase1, apruebaTecnico, rindeExamen, pierdeTecnico ** imprimir cuál es el status de ese alumno...Si uso unos console.log para esas variables luego de las **funciones fase1 y tecnica** me imprime que se guardaron los nombres de esos alumnos, pero en la función final no sé cómo utilizar esas variables con sus valores guardados

Answer (score 1):

No estás accediendo nunca a tu array `datos` para obtener los valores de `nombre` y `ppi`. Tienes que recorrer tu array con `forEach` e ingresar cada uno de los elementos, por lo que tu función quedaría algo así:

```
function final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico) {
  datos.forEach(e => {
    if (apruebaInglesCT && apruebaTecnico) {
      console.log("Hola " + e.nombre + "!!, el detalle de tu status final es: \n En Inglés - " + e.ppi + " puntos- ok");
    } else {
      console.log("nada");
    }
  })
}
```

Y para mostrar los estudiantes que solo aprobaron (por ejemplo, los que tienen más de 50 puntos), puedes hacerlo con este `if`:

```
if ((apruebaInglesCT && apruebaTecnico) && e.ppi > 50)
```

**Código:**

```js
var datos = [];

function agregarEstudiante(nombre, pef, pei, peo, ef, ei, eo, ppi, ct) {
  datos.push({
    nombre: nombre,
    pef: pef, // Puntaje eval. Fundamentos
    pei: pei, // Puntaje eval. prog. Imperativa
    peo: peo, // Puntaje eval. POO
    ef: ef, // Evidencia Fundamentos
    ei: ei, // Evidencia Imperativa
    eo: eo, // Evidencia POO
    ppi: ppi, // Promedio Ingles
    ct: ct, // Lecciones CT
  });
}
agregarEstudiante("Juan", 100, 100, 100, true, true, true, 80, 10);
agregarEstudiante("Pedro", 90, 60, 50, true, false, true, 90, 9);
agregarEstudiante("Pepe", 90, 60, 50, true, false, true, 40, 9);

var apruebaInglesCT = []
var pierdeFase1 = []
function fase1(datos) {
  if (datos.ppi >= 50 && datos.ct === 10) {
    apruebaInglesCT.push(datos.nombre);
  } else {
    pierdeFase1.push(datos.nombre);
  }
}
datos.forEach(fase1);

var apruebaTecnico = []
var rindeExamen = []
var pierdeTecnico = [];
function tecnica(datos) {
  var prom = ((datos.pef * 0.3) + (datos.pei * 0.5) + (datos.peo * 0.2));
  if ((prom >= 60) && (datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)) {
    apruebaTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
  }
  else if ((prom >= 60) && !(datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)) {
    rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre + prom);

  }
  else if ((prom >= 50 && prom < 60) && (datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)) {
    rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre + prom);
  }
  else {
    pierdeTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
  }
}
datos.forEach(tecnica);

function final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico) {
  datos.forEach(e => {
    if ((apruebaInglesCT && apruebaTecnico) && e.ppi > 50) {
      console.log("Hola " + e.nombre + "!!, el detalle de tu status final es: \n En Inglés - " + e.ppi + " puntos - ok");
    } else {
      console.log("Hola " + e.nombre + "!!, lamentablemente usted desaprobó el curso de inglés, el detalle de tu status final es: En Inglés - " + e.ppi);
    }
  })
}
final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico);
```

Comment: Hola Cris, gracias por la respuesta! aquí surge otro problema y es que en la función final no tuvo en cuenta las condiciones del If, es decir, si yo agrego un usuario que repruebe inglés no debería ejecutar el ciclo. Con el datos.forEach accedo a los valores que tiene datos pero excluye las variables antes guardadas como "apruebaInglesCT" y "apruebaTecnico"

Comment: @EvelinDuarte gracias por la observación, me avisa si esto es lo que necesita.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que los alumnos pasan por dos fases, la fase 1 (aprenden ingles) donde pueden aprobar o desaprobar, y la fase técnica donde pueden aprobar, rendir examen o desaprobar, en el caso de que tengan que rendir examen se debe mostrar el promedio. El problema es que lo hiciste demasiado complicado, en los if's donde validas a los que pasaron por 'dar examen' concatenas el nombre con el promedio, quedándote algo como 'Pedro67'... en cualquier caso podría hacerse mucho más fácil pero no quise tocar demasiado porque no sabemos los requisitos del ejercicio

```js
var datos = [];

function agregarEstudiante(nombre, pef, pei, peo, ef, ei, eo, ppi, ct) {
  datos.push({
    nombre: nombre,
    pef: pef, // Puntaje eval. Fundamentos
    pei: pei, // Puntaje eval. prog. Imperativa
    peo: peo, // Puntaje eval. POO
    ef: ef, // Evidencia Fundamentos
    ei: ei, // Evidencia Imperativa
    eo: eo, // Evidencia POO
    ppi: ppi, // Promedio Ingles
    ct: ct, // Lecciones CT
  });
}
agregarEstudiante("Juan", 100, 100, 100, true, true, true, 80, 10);
agregarEstudiante("Pedro", 90, 60, 50, true, false, true, 90, 9);

var apruebaInglesCT = [];
var pierdeFase1 = [];

function fase1(datos) {
  if (datos.ppi >= 50 && datos.ct === 10) {
    apruebaInglesCT.push(datos.nombre);
  } else {
    pierdeFase1.push(datos.nombre);
  }
}
datos.forEach(fase1);

var apruebaTecnico = [];
var rindeExamen = [];
var pierdeTecnico = [];
function tecnica(datos) {
  var prom = datos.pef * 0.3 + datos.pei * 0.5 + datos.peo * 0.2;
  if (prom >= 60 && datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo) {
    apruebaTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
  } else if (prom >= 60 && !(datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo)) {
    rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre); // no pusheo el nombre y el promedio concatenados, sino uno y despues el otro
    rindeExamen.push(prom)
  } else if (prom >= 50 && prom < 60 && datos.ef && datos.ei && datos.eo) {
    rindeExamen.push(datos.nombre);
    rindeExamen.push(datos.prom)
  } else {
    pierdeTecnico.push(datos.nombre);
  }
}
datos.forEach(tecnica);

function final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico) {
  let msjs = [] 
  datos.forEach((elem) => {
    let msj = `Hola ${elem.nombre}!!! el detalle de tu status final es: fase 1: ` // empiezo creando el msj en cada iteracion
    if(apruebaInglesCT.includes(elem.nombre)) msj +='Aprobado.' // dependiendo si la persona se encuentra en X arreglo voy concatenando
    else msj += 'Desaprobado.'
    msj += ' Fase tecnica: '
    if(apruebaTecnico.includes(elem.nombre)) msj += 'Aprobado'
    else if(rindeExamen.includes(elem.nombre)) {
      msj += 'Rinde examen, promedio de '
      msj += `${rindeExamen[rindeExamen.indexOf(elem.nombre) + 1]}` // como se que el promedio se encuentra justo despues del nombre de la persona en el arreglo rindeExamen, lo aprovecho
    }
    else msj = msj.concat('Desaprobado')
    msjs.push(msj)
  })
  return msjs
}

final(datos, apruebaInglesCT, apruebaTecnico).forEach(elem => console.log(elem)) // imprimo
```

en general podría hacerse mejor pero sin los requisitos solo podía tocar por encima, la función 'tecnica' la modifique levemente